# How to parse ant like path

Tags: java, string, parsing, ant

How do I parse paths such as `/aaa/bbb/**/*.java` as used in ant. I guess I could have looked into the source code. Is there is simple solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Ant's [DirectoryScanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794381/how-to-find-files-that-match-a-wildcard-string-in-java).

Comment: I figured there should be a way to use ant. I guess I was a bit lazy to actually research the class available to do the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.split()` to split on the path separator character.  You could then iterate through the resulting array to descend through the directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you might be able to use ant itself for that.. Check out [How to parse and interpret ant's build.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830541/how-to-parse-and-interpret-ants-build-xml). It shows how to get the path used by ant. I am not sure what you are looking to do..